How to Fix npm Error Code EINVALIDTAGNAME When Publishing a Package?
node -v 20.18.0
npm -v 10.9.0
Hello, I have a problem, when I am trying to use any npx init command, I get error. for example npx init prisma
same I get when trying to init husky.
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (5)> npx prisma init
npm error code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm error Invalid tag name "scripts.build=tsc" of package "scripts.build=tsc": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-15T10_09_14_591Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (5)> 

tried update nodejs, uninstalled and reinstalled all global packages, also created another empty nodejs project, but I got same error

What is init? Is it a package or a command for npx? I can't find it.

sorry, my bad. command is: npx prisma init. but error is same with it.

I would try to search for the string scripts.build=tsc in the codebase. From your 3rd line: somewhere - when running the command - it assumes the string is a name of npm package. Which obviously it is not, and probably it is an error in the  command-line, like one space more, copy-pasted invisible character or similar.
